# Plausible way to explain magic

Tags: internal-consistency, magic

In this scenario, the world is our world today. But, recently an ancient script filled with knowledge that hadn't been known in modern science begun to virally spreading, most via internet. It goes with modern memo and explanations, how to video etc., so anyone who experiment on it while follow the guide thoroughly can practice magic just like another cooking recipe book, or fitness guide and achieve the result. Of course government, religion sect, modern science society, and logical people try to banished it, but overtime they too look at it as the missing piece of science and when they try to experiment on it they understand the universe better and over time it can be implemented to leap our technological advancement.

So, my explanation of magic is like this:

We take an analogy of the digital world to our world. Imagine a physic law is like a digital code, and magic is a means to alter the code. The code of the universe is written on so many levels, and every level also need different level of mastery. Like to create a fire ball, is as easy as learning simple CSS. While to alter fire behavior example make the fire to be cold not hot, will require a mastery equal to Phyton language. Of course the highest level allowed you to alter the fabric of the reality itself (but even the ancient script don't have this kind of advance knowledge).

My question is:

Is this kind of magic explanation can be accepted in science based perspective? Is there any existing explanation about possibilities of altering a physic rule ( I mean some real postulate, theory, or hypothesis) ?

Thank you

Comment: Wouldn't you need an enourmous amount of energy to alter the fabric of the universe? Where would you draw that energy from?

Comment: To alter reality with all part of the universe affected, of course. But to just flick a fire in your thumb, I don't think so. Of course channeling the energy are included in the process, and should be from either one of the 2 source: your own energy, or a natural energy that flows around you.

Comment: Sanderson's First Law of Magics states, "An author's ability to solve conflict satisfactorily with magic is directly proportional to how well the reader understands said magic." Closing as Primarily Opinion based.

Comment: The idea sound pretty much like The Matrix.

Comment: Fully explained magic is no longer magical. Everything explained by science to satisfactory level is just science.

Comment: Unfortunately reality is much much more worst than magic, just imagine electrons can be at multiple places at once and changes to one object can somehow affects another which can be trillions of miles away instantaneously and it's only get worse still, the present can influence the past.  I think it should be the other way around your magic scripts run the reality sub-routines...

Answer (score 2):

### The magic is nothing magical, it is still physics.

The thing is that physics is the set of natural laws, how the world works. If you have "magic" in your world, it is the same part of it as gravity etc. Just another force. Just different laws.

If it was there, it was there from the start. You cannot make it like they now found a script and the things started to work that way. They worked like that all the times in past. But same as with other forces in nature, people might had problems to harness it, to know what it is. Look at electricity for example.

Altering physics laws? Nay. They are given and cannot be changed. However, you can prepare a situation, that still gives you the needed results. Because - the real behaviour of the world is **superposition** of ALL physics laws. Superposition of ALL applied forces. The magic is just one more force to take in account.

Answer (score 0):

There are prominent theories postulating that the universe is digital.  [Very likely that the universe is a simulation](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj_4baZhNXQAhUB6YMKHWE4Ca8QFggxMAM&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.extremetech.com%2Fextreme%2F227126-neil-degrasse-tyson-says-its-very-likely-the-universe-is-a-simulation&usg=AFQjCNFTStQmNoCpN5BU0Muv7FKErtYGXA&sig2=kLALck3Eqfbiz51HDA37sQ)  I found this article with this google search: "Proof that the world is digital"

To your second question, this universe is dancing on a pin head balanced on the edge of a razor.  By that I mean, the fundamental physics of this universe are tuned so precisely that and relatively miniscule change in the fundamental forces could would make this universe unrecognizable.

I found [this blog](https://creationofuniverse.wordpress.com/2012/04/23/fundamental-forces/)  which discusses the precarious nature of universe creation.  In short if you could change any the Physics Constants you could in theory change the universe.

Answer (score 0):

I want to extend grldsndrs answer. You could find a way to attract the attention of the virtual machine simulating the universe. Some sort of an escape mechanism that allows you to modify the variables of the universe without the need of extra energy or sorts. Imagine you are the one running the simulation within the computer. Now each cell transfers energy and the total energy in your simulation is fixed. Now imagine you have placed special patterns to aid with debugging or data extraction. A being in that simulation can exploit this to gain advantage. Since he would basically be outside the simulation, he could, with your debugging interface, modify the values of the cells without any validation.